# When i press 'Update all' i get: "Error: Cannot open PivotTable source file '[file1]PivotData' "

Tags: excel

I've created a newer version of an old excel file. The old one is called TargetModel_v1, and the new is TargetModel_v2. When i'm in the new version and press 'Update all' i get the error message: Error: Cannot open PivotTable source file '[TargetModel_v1]PivotData'. But the strange thing is:

1. I only have two PivotTables in TargetModel_v2 and when i update these PivotTables individually they will update just fine.
2. Going to Data -> Quary & Connections i have no connection to nor TargetModel_v1 or TargetModel_v2
3. When i go to Change data source both of my Pivot Tables referer to the correct data within TargetModel_v2
4. There is no macro active between the two files.

I've read all of the relating questions on this matter, without any luck. And after troubleshooting blanks for hours now, so i'm open for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name manager, if [TargetModel_v1]PivotData is stored as a name, delete it.

Check the Power Pivot Data Model, if [TargetModel_v1]PivotData is there, delete it.

I recall a similar issue I could only solve with VBA. To get the exact name of all your connections:

```
For Each Connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  Debug.Print Connection.Name
Next Connection
```

And to delete the specific connection, for example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("[TargetModel_v1]PivotData").Delete
```